# Why is this question marked "too broad"?

Tags: discussion, questions, close-reasons

I am trying to get my head around how to correctly (and quickly) review close votes.

The first one in the queue today was particularly confusing to me. It was closed as Too Broad.

> #### [ie9 's compatiblity with modern html and css language (Cross-browser CSS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24260333/ie9-s-compatiblity-with-modern-html-and-css-language-cross-browser-css)
>
> I made a ultra basic page consist of several divs and set of css
>   rules.
>
> It works perfectly with every browser that i have seen for last 2
>   years. Because of i am new with web i have no idea what can old
>   browsers handle or not. I know that modern scripts like html5 ,
>   javascript , webgl etc will not work with old browsers. However this
>   page is pretty simple as i told. And weird thing is it works with
>   older versions of chrome and firefox. But ie9 completely cant handle
>   most of the css rules...
>
> ```
> <style media="screen" type="text/css">
>   #main
>   {
>    padding:0;
>      margin:0;
>    width:100%;
>    background-image:url(http://www.sisecam.com.tr/ik/index1.4.1.png);
>    background-repeat:no-repeat;
>    background-size:100%;
>    background-color:white;
>   }
>   #warningmsg
>   {
>   position:relative;
>   left:40px;
>   top:30px;
>   }
>   #locatordiv
>   {
>   position:relative;
>   top:436px;
>   }
>   #yellowribbon
>   {
>   width:100%;
>   height:320px;
>   background-image:url(http://www.sisecam.com.tr/ik/index1.4.3.png);
>
>   background-repeat:no-repeat;
>   background-color:#f5c11f;
>   }
>   #loginbutton
>   {
>    margin:0;
>    padding:0;
>    width:100%;
>    display:block;
>    height:35px;
>    position:relative;
>    left:85px;
>    top:50px;
>   }
>   #logo
>   {
>       margin-left:auto;
>       margin-top:90px;
>       background-image:url(http://www.sisecam.com.tr/ik/logo.png);
>       background-repeat:no-repeat;
>       width:100px;
>       height:100px;
>       position:relative;
>       right:20px;
>   }
>   .title
>   {
>       position:relative;
>       left:20px;
>       top:2px;
>       font-size:15px;
>       color:#FFF;
>   }
>   .input
>   {
>       display:block;
>       height:25px;
>       width:160px;
>       background-size:200 40;
>       background-repeat:no-repeat;
>       margin-top:34px;
>       position:relative; 
>       top:55px;
>       left:65px;
>   }
>   input
>   {
>       font-size:17px;
>       width:170px;
>       height:20px;
>       border-style:none;
>       padding:0;
>       outline:none;
>   }
>   body 
>   {
>    background:white;
>   }
>   input[type="submit"] {
>    opacity:0;
>    width:inherit;
>    height:inherit;
>   } 
> </style>
>   Assuming that ie9 can handle divs and their ids ...
> ```
>
> My main problem is css compatibility. Is it possible to write css
>   rules that works with ie9 as it works in rest of the browsers?
>
> Any suggestion will help.

Asking a random individual from the chat, he mentioned the gist was 'How to write CSS rules that will work with IE9 as well as all other modern browsers'.

Which would be too broad. But in my opinion the question is more along the lines of 'why is my CSS not working in IE9'. And he specifically indicates his code, though it is not concise.

It might make sense to ask for symptom details, better wording, down vote, mark too narrow, unclear, etc. But "too broad"? How can this be?

What is the correct way to handle this question, and why?

Answer (score 10):

Here is what appears to be the main question statement:

> My main problem is css compatibility. Is it possible to write css rules that works with ie9 as it wrks in rest of the browsers?

Now imagine that you already knew the answer to that question, and you had to answer it completely. You'd find that:

- It takes an unreasonable amount of work from you to fully answer it.
- You would very likely miss some points that are relevant to the answer.

That is why it's too broad.

Comment: I thought about that. But he isn't asking 'how', he's just questioning whether it is possible/reasonable. Am I wrong? If I'm right the answer to that portion would just be "Yes".

Comment: @GeorgeBailey  Almost anyone who asks "is it possible" is really asking for "how".  Answering an "is it possible" question with "yes" deserves downvotes

Comment: I think that is only a piece of the question and therefore only a piece of the answer.

Comment: I feel it is obvious that his primary goal is to know why his page isn't working in IE9, and to keep from making the same mistake? That individual paragraph is his 'first question', not really 'question summary'. What do you think?

Comment: @GeorgeBailey That question isn't being asked in an answerable way. It's just ~100 lines of code that "ie9 completely cant handle". That would be closed as off-topic / 'question seeking debugging help...'

Comment: @Andrew has it right: "ie9 completely cant handle most of the css rules" is not quite specific problem definition. Most..er..which for example??